# How to revert back to an original namespace once its name is modified?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, stlport

I'm using a library called stlport, which redefines the `std` namespace like this:

```
# if defined (_STLP_REDEFINE_STD)
/*  We redefine "std" to "stlport", so that user code may use std:: transparently */
#   undef  std
#   define std STLPORT
# else
```

Because of this, where-ever in my code I try to use `std::something`, it gets substituted with `_STLP::something`.

If I comment out the `#define std STLPORT` line, my legacy project's code won't compile (it's stlport dependent).

If I don't comment out the line, the new library I'm trying to add won't compile because it uses `std::` with a different set of allocators from what stlport uses. Type clashes.

I've tried `#define STLPORT std` in a line just before including the new library, but this #define just doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to use the normal `std` once it gets redefined like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different implementations of STL, one in the STLPORT and one in the standard library. Your old code needs STLPORT and your new code needs the standard library.

Both new and old code use things like `include <vector>` but they need **different** include files named `vector`, and hence different `-I` compiler flags. You cannot compile them with the same compiler settings.

If you don't need to exchange standard containers and other STL-related data between old and new code, you can compile old code with the STLPORT settings and the new code with the regular settings. Do not touch STLPORT includes, do not redefine `std` in your code. STLPORT is not meant to be used like that. It is intended as a drop-in replacement for the (parts of) the standard library. You select which one you use by choosing the right compiler flags, not by modifying your (or STLPORT) source.

If you do need to exchange standard containers between old and new code, you are out of luck. Your only recourse is to modify the legacy code such that it conforms to the standard.

Comment: I don't need to exchange standard containers, but if I'm to use `-I`, then I'd have to keep the new code as part of a separate project in the solution, right? I can't use the new code in the same project as the old code?I've been stuck with this problem for a month now, and your answer has given such a relief! Thank you! What I was gonna try next was `/D` to replace stlport with std.

Comment: I am not that much familiar with Visual Studio. Perhaps the easiest solution is to keep old and new code in different projects, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
# if defined (_STLP_REDEFINE_STD)
#   undef  std
#   define std STLPORT
# else

//....

#ifdef std
#define std_WAS_DEFINED
#undef std
#endif

//new code

#ifdef std_WAS_DEFINED
#define std STLPORT
#endif

//legacy code
```

Comment: `#undef std` worked, but now I think `std` contains nothing. I tried `#include<vector>` and `std::vector<int> v;` and got this error:  *59 IntelliSense: namespace "std" has no member "vector"*, until I used #include *"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector"* and the errors went away. Is there a way to make the entire `std` namespace come back? Or a way to see what's contained in the namespace?

Comment: @Nav Have you actually compiled? Intellisense isn't a compiler.

Comment: I know...I did compile, and there was no compiler error, but my questions remain.

Comment: @Nav the question doesn't remain. Intellisense doesn't see `vector`, or it still thinks `std` is defined. Don't put your faith in it.

Comment: No I meant the questions "is there a way to make the std namespace come back" and "a way to see what's contained in a namespace"